# Can't seem to get the right value in a for loop with and if-else statement

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
    int numArray [] = {1, 7, 6, 4, 5, 9};

    int high = 0,low = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < 2; count++) {
        if (count == 0) {
            for (int countA = 0; countA < numArray.length-1; countA++) { //The increment expression is invoked after each iteration/time through the loop.
                high = numArray[countA];
                if (high < numArray[countA+1]) {
                    high = numArray[countA+1];
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int countB = 0; countB < numArray.length-1; countB++) {
                low = numArray[countB];
                if (low > numArray[countB+1]) {
                    low = numArray[countB+1];
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

When I print the value for low from else block, it prints 5 instead of the expected value of 1. Why is this?

Comment: What happened when you stepped through this with a debugger, or at least a piece of paper and a pencil?

Comment: Well I used eclipse to compile this and it gave me 5. What I did was I copied the for loop from the outermost if-statement and pasted it in the else block.

Comment: The logic you use for determining high and low is flawed; with a different int array your high would be incorrect as well

Comment: Okay thanks, I was thinking if turning it into methods will help.

Comment: Look through the last loop carefully, pretend you're a computer program and do each step yourself.  What will the program do when `countB` is 4?

Comment: 5 > 9 = false so it wouldn't do the block of code.

Comment: @user3166710 *Which* block of code wouldn't it do?  Look at the _entire_ block of code inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Oh yeah, it starts with 1 which is already the lowest number. So it doesn't do the if statement. I think I might have a solution, I could make high = numArray[0] and then only change it through an if statement when there is a number bigger than it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other responders have given you a better way to write this, but to specifically address your original question, the reason you're getting an "unexpected" (to you) value of "low" is that you're assigning each entry of the array to "low" unconditionally.  The entry with "5" is the last entry that you process, so that's the value you end up with.

To address this specific problem, you might assign the array entry value to a new local variable, called "newlow", perhaps.  Then, compare "newlow" to the existing "low" value and then conditionally assign it, perhaps like this:

```
            low = numArray[0];
            for (int countB = 0; countB < numArray.length-1; countB++) {
                int newlow = numArray[countB];
                if (newlow < low) {
                    low = newlow;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You mean numArray.length without subtracting it right?

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the array (or a clone of the array) like so

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int numArray [] = {1, 7, 6, 4, 5, 9};
  int [] copy = numArray.clone();
  Arrays.sort(copy);

  int high = copy[copy.length - 1],low = copy[0];
  System.out.printf("Values = %s, Low = %d, High = %d\n", 
      java.util.Arrays.toString(numArray), low, high);
}
```

Which outputs

```
Values = [1, 7, 6, 4, 5, 9], Low = 1, High = 9
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you give a little extra explanation?

Comment: On which part? This sorts a `copy` of your `numArray` and then pulls the highest and lowest values... (remember once it is sorted, the lowest value is first and the highest value is last).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not really answering your question, but the code:

```
for (int count = 0; count < 2; count++) {
  if (count==0) {
    doSomething();
  } else {
    doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

does exactly the same as

```
doSomething();
doSomethingElse();
```

Always consider the [KISS Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, I could use that to shorter blocks of code later on.